# Flutter- DropdownMenuItem value bind problem

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to bind value into DDL. Facing a problem while binding the value.I've to send desc and code to backend. Now the DropdownMenuItem value aren't binding. It's showing *int can't be assigned to the parameter type DropDownDataModel*

```
DropdownButton<DropDownDataModel>(
  isExpanded: true,
  underline: Container(),
  value: dropdownvalue,
  items: attempt.attemptList.map((items) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<DropDownDataModel>(
          value: items.code,
          child: Text(items.desc),
          );
           }).toList(),
  onChanged: (value) {
      print('value ${value}');
      setState(() {
       dropdownvalue = value;
       attempt.desc = value.name;
       attempt.code = attempt.attemptList[value.value].code;
       });
 })
```

Comment: what is the type of dropdownvalue ?

Comment: I've declared it as *var*

Comment: dropdownvalue should be DropDownDataModel

Comment: Can you include `attempt`

Comment: #Yeasin attempt is list data that comes from API. Inside it a field named attemptList, I've to bind this value into DDL and I've to pass code and desc for the selected dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

i think the error is here

```
value: dropdownvalue,
```

the `dropdownvalue` is not a `DropDownDataModel` which should be, because that's the value of the `DropdownButton`.

So the first option, if you want to assign an `int` to `dropdownvalue` instead of `DropDownDataModel`, then you should declare as follows:

```
DropdownButton<int>
```

or if you want the value to be `DropDownDataModel`, then you should change the `dropdownvalue` to hold a `DropDownDataModel`, as follows:

```
var DropDownDataModel? dropdownvalue;
```